# Does Scala io.Source.FromFile return any kind of exception?

Tags: scala, file, exception, ioexception

I was reviewing my code for the last time searching for exceptions when I stopped on this line of code:

```
var list: Array[String] = Source.fromFile(this.Path).getLines.toArray
```

I searched in the documentation on scala-lang but it seems that none of the methods of that line throws any kind of `ioException`...
How is that possible?

**EDIT:**

```
try {
  var list: Array[String] = Source.fromFile("").getLines.toArray
}
catch {
  case ex:Exception => println(ex.getMessage)
}
```

does not print anything, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked exceptions are enforced by the javac, the JVM don't really know about them. And contrary to Java, Scala doesn't care about checked exceptions.

Look at [Source](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src//library/scala/io/Source.scala#L1) for instance, you won't notice any code dealing with exceptions. Something that is impossible in good old Java, which would require `try`/`catch`s or `throws` clauses.

Despite that, a Scala library author may still want to make sure that Java users check for these exceptions, so there is the [@throws](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/throws.html) annotation, which let you declare that a method may throw a exception just like `throws` Java clause. Make sure to keep in mind that `@throws` is only for Java consumption.

You may also want to take look at [scala.util.control.Exception](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/util/control/Exception%24.html). It contains all sorts of goodies for dealing with exceptions.

Comment: I understand that the authors decided not to use checked exceptions, but at least they should write the throwable exceptions in the doc!

Comment: I also understand that in java it is hateful to write every exception in the throws clause, but I like the idea that the compiler should warn you about them! As the things are, there are no ways to write good code in Scala, because or you ignore exceptions and let your program crash silently, or you wrap all your code in try-catch! How is that possible?!

Comment: @DDB, It was certainly a design decision. I don't think it's all that bad. Now, to dealing with exceptions I strongly recommend that you take a deep look at control.Exception, there you will find utilities that can help you deal with exceptions without resorting to try/catch.

Comment: @DDB, One more thing: Scala is not Java :)

Comment: I know, but if I did not know java I couldn't know what exception that line could throw (thanks @Don Roby) ! One thing is that Scala does not force you to catch exceptions, another is to not warm me about their existence! An I the only one unsatisfied about this?

Comment: @DDB, yeah, after giving some more thought about it I think having something to tell you that a program is not checking every possible checked exception might be nice. Specially in the case of using existing Java libs.

Answer (score 1):

`Source.fromFile` calls `java.io.FileInputStream.open`, which throws a `FileNotFoundException` if you give it a nonexistent file.

`Source.fromFile` doesn't catch this, so it will be seen in your code.

I suspect many of the other exceptions possible in the `java.io` package are similarly unhandled, but apparently undocumented.

Comment: So scala doc has bad documentation... Any way (passing some parameters to compiler) to know what are the exceptions that my methods throw?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I figured that much out just by doing it and seeing the exception.

Comment: Now I'm wondering how many not documented exceptions could it throw... FileNotFoundException, ioException some other related to permissions... At scala-lang should spend more time improving what they have than creating new code...